# Anti forgery token as header field or as Post value on AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, csrf

I'm working now on [Ring Anti Forgery](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-anti-forgery) to prevent the site from CSRF attacks. Now I'm in doubt if I should pass the token as a header field or as a `post` value on AJAX request as they both seem to work.

On the doc it says:

> The middleware also looks for the token in the X-CSRF-Token and
>   X-XSRF-Token header fields, which are commonly used in AJAX requests.

The downside of setting it to a header field on my side is that I have to change every Jquery `$.post` to a simple `$.ajax` so I can set the headers.

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    username: username, 
    sender: sender
  },
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token": X_CSRF_Token,   
  }
});
```

vs.

```
$.post( "url", { username: username, sender: sender, '__anti-forgery-token': X_CSRF_Token})
  .done(function( data ) {
  // done
});
```

Is there a need for me to change every jQuery `$.post` to a `$.ajax` so I can set the anti forgery token as a header field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set the CSRF token at every ajax call: https://gist.github.com/alanhamlett/6316427